# Print statement inside TensorFlow function

Tags: python, logging, tensorflow

I am new to TensorFlow and I am trying to print the shape of a vector inside a function which will be called from a TensorFlow session.

The problem is that this line (showed commented out) is only executed when this function template is initially defined (and not at every iteration during a TensorFlow session). How do I add a print statement such that it is called at every TensorFlow iteration?

```py
def Q(X):
    # f_debug.write('Q(X) :: X.shape :: ' + str(X.shape) + '\n')

    h = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X, Q_W1) + Q_b1)
    z = tf.matmul(h, Q_W2) + Q_b2
    return z
```

Comment: Is `f_debug` just a file that you're outputting your debug information to?

Comment: Is there is a reason you can't just use the `print()` function built into python?

Comment: The challenge is that the function Q is probably not run every TF iteration either. Later on in the code, the handle `z` will be resolved on each iteration, causing a chain of resolutions of TF nodes that it depends on, like the handle `h`. You can use `tf.print` to add a print node as a dependency to z that will print out when z is resolved.

Comment: This took me forever to understand with my code, but functions like `Q` are just "graph builder" functions, that are returning a handle node (a tensor) like `z` that can be executed/resolved later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an important point to note and a common confusion in TF. That function will NOT be called by tensorflow in a session, no python function will, with the exception of `tf.py_func`, which could be a workaround to your problem.

Tensorflow calls your function `Q` only to get the symbolic operations and then adds those operations to the dependency graph. During a session, the dependency graph is all that is relied upon to perform computations. Even if you are using a `tf.while`, `tf.cond`, or other control flow operation. None of these call python during a session, they just loop over elements in the dependency graph as you defined.

In general there's no good way to stop the execution of tensorflow mid-graph execution short of using the Tensorflow Debugger (which is not hard to configure at all). But as a workaround you might get away with defining a `tf.py_func` python function. This function marshals a tensor into a python object and calls python during session execution (it's not efficient or anything, but it's handy in certain cases).

You may need to use `with tf.control_dependencies(...):` to force your `tf.py_func` operation to run (since it wouldn't have any dependency if it had nothing but a print statement inside of it).

Disclamer: I haven't used `tf.py_func` this way nor was it built with this intention.

Answer (score 0):

*This is a TensorFlow 1 specific explanation. I'm sure Eager Execution in TF 2 changes some of these things. See [docs for tf.print](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/print?hl=en).*

I have not had any luck using regular `print()` statements inside py_func functions. You *can* do print statements "inside" the execution of your TF graph (py_func or otherwise) using `tf.print`. I'm only familiar with its use in TF 1, but there it works by creating a new print operation and adding it to the TF graph:

```
def Q(X):
    # Note that at least sometimes, X.shape can be resolved before the
    # graph is executed, so you may only need this for the *value* of X

    # Create a new print op
    printop = tf.print('Q:', X)

    # Force printop to be added to the graph by setting it as a 
    # dependency for at least one operation that will be run
    with tf.control_dependencies([printop]):
        h = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X, Q_W1) + Q_b1)
        z = tf.matmul(h, Q_W2) + Q_b2
        return z
```

I *have* run into some situations where this didn't work as I'd hoped (I believe due to multithreading). It also can be tricky if you can't find a node of the graph to attach the `printop` operation to--if you are trying to print something on the last line of a function, for example.

But this seems to work much of the time for me.

[Docs on tf.print()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/print?hl=en).